# Change chrome application shortcut icon on taskbar in linux mint

Tags: shortcuts, icons, linux-mint, web-application, gnome-panel

I use a lot of web applications on Linux Mint. I'm confused with the icons being the chrome-icon all the time i.e. the same icon for all running programs.

So how can I change the Chrome application shortcut icon on the taskbar? (not in menu nor in panel).

I'm talking about this area:

[image]

How do I make (for example) web application "Trello" to have a Trello icon?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 21 with Cinnamon Desktop, the icons are managed by the .desktop file for each program.
These are typically located within `/usr/share/applications`. For example Firefox is located at `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`

If you open the file in a text editor as root and find the `icon` key, then you can swap it out with a path to your favourite icon.

`sudo xed /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`

By default it won't have a file path set but will just say `firefox`, this is a reference to different themed icons located within `/usr/share/icons`. Inside here will be a directory for each theme and inside those more directories for different icon sizes, but eventually one will be called `firefox.png`.

Update the path to an icon of your choice and save the file.
[image: Text editor showing xed]

When you re-open that application it will have the new icon.

[image: Firefox with the gvim icon]

Depending on how the application was installed, the `.desktop` file may also be located within `~/.local/share/applications`

I don't know exactly what version of Mint you were running in this picture, but I've checked Mint 13 with the cinnamon desktop and it is mostly the same, instead of `xed` you have `gedit` installed so use that instead.

Sadly I couldn't find the Trello web app, it may not exist any more if you have another example I can look into that.